# C# Converting byte array to jsonstring returns string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

So I am using a Java and C# Application to send a byte array to a webservice.
Sending the byte array using java works but with c# it doesn't, because when I convert the c# byte array to a json string the byte array is a string.

`{"fileId":0,"fileName":"PrivateFile.java","fileContent":"LyoNCiAqIFRvIGNoYW5nZSB0aGlzI......."}`

As you can see there are the `""` quotes in the bytearray.
This means when I try to convert the jsonstring in a object again, it won't work because the webservice will try to convert the string into a byte array: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 58 path $.fileContent`

Converting the byte array to a jsonstring in java using gson looks like this:

```
{"fileId":0,"fileName":"Database.java","fileContent":[47,42,13,10,32,42,32,84,111,32,99,104,97,110,103,101,32,116,104,105,115,32,108,105,99,101,110,115,101,32,104,101,97,100,101,114,44,32,99,104,111,111,115,101,32,76,105,99,101,110]}
```

as you can see the syntax is right because there are no `""` between the byte array. So I am able to convert it as a byte array again.

Here is how I convert the byte array to a jsonString in C#:

```
PublicFile p = new PublicFile();
p.fileId = 0;
p.fileName = tokens[cnt - 1];
p.fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(myFilePath); 
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
```

How can I properly serialize a byte array to a json string in c#?

Comment: It looks like the content is being represented as base64 in C#, which I'd expect as a generally much more pleasant representation of a byte array than as individual values.

Comment: If you want a base64 string  just convert before serialising : `public static string FileToBase64(string path) => FileToBase64(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
public static string FileToBase64(Byte[] bytes) => Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);`. And the counter part to have a byte array from string64 is `public static Byte[] Base64ToBytes(string b64Str) => Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str);`

Comment: Btw you want the 1rst or the 2nd result?

Comment: @xdtTransform i guess I want the second result. because I want to sent the byte array to the webservice not the string of the byte array

Comment: It does not work: Additional information: The input is not a valid base 64 string because it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two spaces, or a space in the spaces that is invalid.

Comment: Hum ok, I got your issue now.  Newtonsoft.Json converts `bytes[]` to it's Base64 string representation. what you want is a Bson not a Json. There is a Newtonsoft.Json.bson lib.

Comment: with either a custom `JsonConverter` or an int[].